# Datalist name not declared when using Code Behind. aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, datalist

I'm a totally newbie to .NET programming, and trying to get some stuff off the ground.

I've run some code which extracts data from a database and presents it into a Datalist. It works fine when the script is on the aspx file, but when I transfer it to a code behind I get the following error

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'showIt' is not declared.
```

(showIt is the ID of the Datalist)

Obviously, the Datalist markup is in my aspx page, and the script is in the code behind .vb file.

As I say, it all works when the scripts are all on the one .aspx file.

The code in the code behind is: (I've skipped the SQL and connection strings to keep this post concise)

```
Partial Public Class Data
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim objDataReader As OdbcDataReader
    objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    showIt.DataSource = objDataReader
    showIt.DataBind()
    objDataReader.Close()
end sub
end class
```

The aspx file looks like this: (again simplified, basic HTML markup etc removed)

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dataOut.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default"%>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:DataList ID="showIt" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">  
<ItemTemplate>    
 <div style="width:300px; display:inline-block; height: 200px; overflow:hidden">
        <div style="width:100%; background:#880000; border-bottom: solid 1px black"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "item") %></div>
        <br />
        <%# Data.stockDisplay(Eval("shopstock"))%>
        <div style="clear: both"><%# Left(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "description"),150) %></div>
 </div>          
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha.... I've fixed it!

needed to declare the DataList before the function so it became publicly available... or at least I think that was the issue, it works now anyway

```
Protected WithEvents showIt As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList
```

I now have other issues... that can go in another question though!